# ASP.Net gridview data get invisible on click of page number

Tags: asp.net, gridview, webforms

My  web application consist of two gridview .On click of id in the first gridviewi.e Gridview1 the second gridview will get populated  with that id detail in the modalpopupextender .So while clicking on the page  numkber of second gridview the gridview display get invisible.After loading that page the second gridview get display

So  where isthe problem i m not getting

Comment: Show the Markup and code behinds concerning your First and second grid view

Comment: i agree with Flop show us your code so that we can help you on this